# How to find the critical points of this linear map?(when is this linear map not surjective?)

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given that $ϕ$ is a map from $n×n$ real matrices to $n×n$ symmetrical matrices such that$$ϕ(B) = A^TB+B^TA.\quad A,B\in M(n,\mathbb R)$$
>   When is this map surjective?

This is my question,and critical points are those where the map is not surjective , mind that it is a linear map from an $n×n$ linear space to a $\dfrac{1}{2}n(n+1)$ linear space.

Comment: the question is contained in the photo.

Comment: if $A$ is invertible, then it is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how the critical points of $A$ can help here.

Anyway, if $A$ is non-singular and $S$ is symmetric, the equation $\phi(B)=A^TB+B^TA=S$ is solved by $B=\frac12(A^T)^{-1}S$.

On the other hand, if $A$ is singular and $0\ne x\in\ker(A)$, then $x^T\phi(B)x=0$ and hence $\phi(B)$ cannot be positive or negative definite.

Therefore, $\phi$ is surjective if and only if $A$ is non-singular.

Comment: Thank you very much , I am just lost in the calculation of components, but you have solved this in some more general sense.